# Grok plugin of Logstash ordered field problem

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have a question about the grok plugin:

I have some logs which are built in the following way and my problem is that the order of my fields can mutate from log to log (in the example here I should extract from all the logs both the `user id` and the `document id`). So I am wondering how I should build the grok 
pattern to handle both the logs. I'm hoping there is a better solution of writing two different patterns (or how to write a regex to find a specific attribute anywhere in the log without knowing before its exact position)

```
2019-01-15 INFO myclass - mymethod: user id: 12345 custom message 1 document id: 843572309845
2019-01-15 WARN myclass - mymethod1: document id: 43543534 custom message 2 user id: 98589348543 custom message 3 agent id: 98435734
```

the expected result is:

```
date: 2019-01-15 
level: INFO
class: myclass
method: mymethod
message: user id: 12345 custom message 1 document id: 843572309845
userId: 12345
documentId: 843572309845

date: 2019-01-15
level: WARN
class: myclass
method: mymethod1
message: document id: 43543534 custom message 2 user id: 98589348543 custom message 3 agent id: 98435734
userId: 98589348543
documentId: 43543534
agentId: 98589348543
```

Looking forward for your answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found a regex where it works (at least in the [grok debugger](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match)):

```
(?=.*user id: %{NUMBER:userId})(?=.*document id: %{NUMBER:documentId})
```

Using it, I was able to get hose results:

```
userId  12345
documentId  843572309845 

userId  98589348543
documentId  43543534
```

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I was searching for